# Difference between service and model in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm discovering Angular2 and I found a quick start project  on internet to understand the structure. I have three folders inside of another: components, services and models. 
I understand what is a component and as I understand a service is a singleton where I want to persist my data.

The thing is that I have this file inside services folder:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Task} from "../models/task";

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {

    private tasks:Array<Task> = [
        new Task("Task 1", false),
        new Task("Task 2", false),
        new Task("Task 3", false),
    ];

    getTasks():Array<Task> {
        return this.tasks;
    }

    addTask(name:string) {
        this.tasks.push(new Task(name, false));
    }

}
```

And I have this one inside models folder:

```
export class Task {

    constructor(public name:string, public done:boolean) {
    }

    toggleDone() {
        this.done = !this.done;
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure why Task is considered a model and TaskService a service.
Is it because I can have multiple instances of Tasks? If so, then can I have multiple instances of TaskService and is not a singleton? If not, how can the compiler know when it is a service and when it is a model? Because of the suffix?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`@Injectable` is the answer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers)

We register an injectable class, and we won't have to instantiate it!

We register it as a provider in the app modules, register it as a provider in our component, and hey presto you're gonna get that injected, straight magic, thanks Angular, you dat boi.

And what's more, now our component won't even have to know anything about the Task class - it's already included in our Injectable service.

Answer (score 4):

Model : the structure of your object (how your object should look like). You can also provide in the constructor how to create an instance of your object.

```
constructor(public name:string, public done:boolean) {
}
```

Service: brain of your component. Do all the hard work (get/send data, calculation, ...). You can identify them thanks to the decorator `@Injectable()`. When you create a service class, you have to tell the provider how create an instance of your service by registering them in the component providers that use them or app module if several components use them across the app.

I suggest to read the literature about angular 2 architecture :
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to prevent you from creating many instances of service. But it's just not the way it's designed. Take a look at this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

> Do we new the HeroService? No way!
> We could create a new instance of the HeroService with new like this:
>
> heroService = new HeroService(); // don't do this
> That's a bad idea for several reasons including
>
> Our component has to know how to create a HeroService. If we ever change the HeroService constructor, we'll have to find every place we create the service and fix it. Running around patching code is error prone and adds to the test burden.
>
> We create a new service each time we use new. What if the service should cache heroes and share that cache with others? We couldn't do that.
>
> We're locking the AppComponent into a specific implementation of the HeroService. It will be hard to switch implementations for different scenarios. Can we operate offline? Will we need different mocked versions under test? Not easy.
>
> What if ... what if ... Hey, we've got work to do!
>
> We get it. Really we do. But it is so ridiculously easy to avoid these problems that there is no excuse for doing it wrong.